# Android - JSON mySQL query gives NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, mysql, database, json

I am trying to run this activity in order to query a database for populating a table.
I have tried to follow a snippet I found online, the only problem is, no matter what, I get "connectionandroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" error.

I have tried to put in an handler, as suggested in many forums, using AsyncTask and do it in background, but still nothing.
I know the error appears when a long query is sent to a database, but this query takes 0.1s, probably. I have the db locally, although accessing it with public IP, and the db is extremely small.

Here my PHP code:

```
<?php

$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="DB";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="pwd";

mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost);

$sql=mysql_query("select * from friendlist where Id1 = 1");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

The code works, as if I go to the page, I see displayed the results (I only have 3 rows for the moment).

Here is the java part:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MySQLAndroidActivity extends ListActivity {

JSONArray jArray;
String result = null;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb=null;
HttpResponse response;
HttpEntity entity;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
//http post
try{
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://X.X.X.X/test.php");

 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

 entity = response.getEntity();


 is = entity.getContent();

 }catch(Exception e){
     Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
     System.exit(1);
}

//convert response to string
try{
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
   sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

   String line="0";
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
          Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
//parsing data
String idfriend;
String id1;
String id2;
try{
  jArray = new JSONArray(result);
  JSONObject json_data=null;
  for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
         json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
         idfriend=json_data.getString("Idfriend");
         id1=json_data.getString("Id1");
         id2=json_data.getString("Id2");


         System.out.println("id1: " + id1);
     }
  }
  catch(JSONException e1){
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Id found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (ParseException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
 }
}
}
```

I tried also using a simple Activity and not a ListActivity.

I have an almost similar code, but that one uses a different method. In fact, it doesnt get the result, on php, it just returns a characters whether there are 0 or more rows retrieved. In this case I need something on a higher level, as I will need to get the values of some specific fields.

EDIT:

As requested, the stacktrace:

```
  Error in http connectionandroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
  04-17 06:44:17.921: W/System.err(24207): java.lang.Exception
  04-17 06:44:17.921: W/System.err(24207):  at       com.mysql.android.MySQLAndroidActivity.onCreate(MySQLAndroidActivity.java:56)
  04-17 06:44:17.921: W/System.err(24207):  at       android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
  04-17 06:44:17.921: W/System.err(24207):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
  04-17 06:44:17.921: W/System.err(24207):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
  04-17 06:44:17.921: W/System.err(24207):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
  04-17 06:44:17.921: W/System.err(24207):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
  04-17 06:44:17.921: W/System.err(24207):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
  04-17 06:44:17.921: W/System.err(24207):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  04-17 06:44:17.921: W/System.err(24207):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  04-17 06:44:17.931: W/System.err(24207):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
  04-17 06:44:17.931: W/System.err(24207):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  04-17 06:44:17.931: W/System.err(24207):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  04-17 06:44:17.931: W/System.err(24207):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
  04-17 06:44:17.931: W/System.err(24207):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
  04-17 06:44:17.931: W/System.err(24207):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT2:

Here is something very similar to the version I did with the AsyncTask (I am creating it on the fly, without a compiler, so it might not be perfect; but it is very similar to the one I did before):

```
  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

      new LoadTask().execute();

  }



 private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    synchronized (this) {

                    Looper.prepare();       
                    doStuff() //this method basically contains what it is inside the onCreate.

                    }

                    return null;
            }

       }
       }
```

**- I recall that I was forced to use 'Looper.prepare();'.
So I added it before 'doStuff();'**

EDIT 2:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MySQLAndroidActivity extends ListActivity {

    JSONArray jArray;
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpEntity entity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        new LoadTask.execute();

    }



    private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask < Void, Integer, Void > {@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {

            Looper.prepare();

            doStuff();



            return null;


        }
    }


    public void doStuff() {
        ArrayList < NameValuePair > nameValuePairs = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > ();
        //http post
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://X.X.X.X/test.php");

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            entity = response.getEntity();


            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            System.exit(1);
        }


        //convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

            String line = "0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        //parsing data
        String idfriend;
        String id1;
        String id2;
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data = null;

            System.out.println("Length " + jArray.length());
            Log.d("DB", "Length " + jArray.length());

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                System.out.println("counter " + i);
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                idfriend = json_data.getString("Idfriend");
                id1 = json_data.getString("Id1");
                id2 = json_data.getString("Id2");


                System.out.println("id1: " + id1);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            Log.d("DB", "Error somewhere");
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

N.

Comment: Please include a stack trace.

Comment: Ok, it was my ignorance. I just added the stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I heard that starting from ICS, it is not allowed to perform network operations on UI (main) thread. Therefore, you must need to perform this operation in a separate thread. So either use **AsyncTask**, **Thread** or **HandlerThread *with Looper and Handler*** to perform web operation. If you try it on a device running froyo or gingerbread, it would be fine but not on ICS.

Regarding your attempt to run it via handler or AsyncTask, it depends on how you did it. Paste that code so i see the problem.

---

**Update**

```
public class MySQLAndroidActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String url = "http://X.X.X.X/test.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

        LoadTask t = new LoadTask();
        t.execute(null);

    }

    private static class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            doStuff();

            return null;
        }
    }





    public static void doStuff() {
        JSONArray jArray;
        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpEntity entity;

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // http post
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            entity = response.getEntity();

            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

            Log.i("json string", result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }


        // parsing data
        String idfriend;
        String id1;
        String id2;
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data = null;

            System.out.println("Length " + jArray.length());
            Log.d("DB", "Length " + jArray.length());

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                System.out.println("counter " + i);
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                idfriend = json_data.getString("idfriend");
                id1 = json_data.getString("id1");
                id2 = json_data.getString("id2");

                System.out.println("id1: " + id1);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            Log.d("DB", "Error somewhere");
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

*There were some method calling issues and the most important was that you were fetching keys out from JSONObject as **Idfriend, Id1, Id2** which is wrong because in your json string the keys are like **idfriend, id1, id2**. Its case-sensitive, thats why it was crashing.

Comment: As I said, I tried to run it on an AsyncTask, didnt work. I was required to use Looper.prepare() and then nothing happened. It was never going into the final 'for-loop'

Comment: in AsyncTask pattern, enclose your **doStuff()** operation in a `try/catch` block and see the difference. Moreover, you dont need to mention *synchronized (this)* in *doInBackground*

Comment: As I said, using an AsyncTask, the app does not crash. I tried to check the size of 'jArray()' and it was correct. The only problem was that it was not entering the for-loop. Is it because of the Looper.prepare()? Basically the size of the array was 2, but it never entered the loop. I also tried to move the for loop outside the AsyncTask, but then it was crashing (dont remember the error).

Comment: did you try my recommendation?

Comment: I tried without synchronized, but it didnt make much difference. But I can try again later. Why would it skip just the for-loop? I dont get it.

Comment: if an exception is thrown while running with-in the loop, it breaks it, unless you are handling exceptions there too

Comment: I have tried right now. As I said, the app doesnt crash. But no message is displayed, neither an error nor a system.out

Comment: Of course, as I said the jArray has the correct length. The problem is inside the for-loop at the end, where the app should display the objects. Is it because of the looper.prepare()?

Comment: if you are doing/displaying something by updating UI in **doStuff()** then its not allowed since it might not be executed on UI thread. Why dont you simply put all your code that you tried with AsyncTask rather then making me to guess?

Comment: If I find a private way, I can send you the link to the php page I am using, so you can test it directly.

Comment: did you try without **Looper.prepare();**? I dont find anything strange in your doStuff.

Comment: you can send me via chat if you want to

Comment: Yes, but as far as I remember it was explicitly asking for it. But I will come back to you, because I want to try it in an environment I know works. (I have a colleagues testing it on his side on his PC)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10168/discussion-between-waqas-and-n3sh)

Answer (score 0):

You should read abou model-view-controller pattern (look it up in google). This pattern defines that you should implement separately the view (user interfaces) from model (database accesses. Read about Dao pattern) and from controller (the logic that runs the application, for example these are the main classes).

Hope this helps you!