# Android: how to upload image in mysql using php

Tags: php, android, mysql, image

I have image in ImageView that is selected by the user ... how can i insert it to mysql database table using php?

can anyone help me with that.

the type of column that i want image to save on it is Blob.

Comment: @jtheman

imageView.buildDrawingCache();
bmIcone = imageView.getDrawingCache();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bmIcone.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); 
byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
            
namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",image_str));

php code

$base= $_REQUEST['image'];
$buffer = base64_decode($base);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK that i found a solution for my question

code in java assuming that the image is already converted to bitmap:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmIcone.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
        byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
        namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", image_str));
```

in server :

```
$base= $_REQUEST['image'];
    $buffer = base64_decode($base);

    $buffer = mysql_real_escape_string($buffer);
```

then inserting the $buffer to table blob column type

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to call your php in android. Many answers already exist on this topic:

- [Call PHP function from android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312728/call-php-function-from-android)
- http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/

To answer your question, this tutorial teaches you how to write your php to store images in MySQL:

- http://forum.codecall.net/topic/40286-tutorial-storing-images-in-mysql-with-php/

Comment: thx for your help but the tutorial u gave it to me is for html page.

android is different i think.. what i am doing right now is converting the ImageView to a bitmap and then convert the bitmap to String by encoding it using base64 ,then send it to php and decode it ... the problem is how can i insert it into table after decoding it? ... or is there any different solution for inserting image to mysql tables?