# From a image into my android phone to blob mysql remote database

Tags: android, mysql

I have a image save in me phone with android 4.4 .

In properties (of the image) says location:"/storage/emulated/0/bluetooth/p.png".

Now, the problem is, I wanna uploading this image (p.png) by my android applicacion to a remote mysql database. It has a field calls photos and is definied as blob.

I´m trying this code. but i dont works. it doesnt give me an error, but the phono never appears in the table of my database. (the coneccion with database is OK).

```
 public void setImage() throws  Exception
{
    crearConexion();
    System.out.println("Entre");

    String q="insert into clientes(imagen) values (?) where id_cliente=1;";

        try {




          String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/bluetooth/p.png";
          InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));


          PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(q);
          statement.setBlob(1, inputStream);
          statement.executeUpdate();

     System.out.println("Terminee");}
          catch (Exception e) {
                 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("ERROR SQLlogHA");
            } finally {



        }

}
```

So please give an example of how upload a photo in my phone and save ir in mysql remote data base with a blob fild.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use web services to link your application with the database.

M aybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/15173589/4364031

Comment: thank you for the answer. But there isnt problem with conecction form my app to the DB.