# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Tags: android

I've searched the other similar questions but none of it works for me so I want to ask you guys.

```
  02-07 18:39:03.953 6252-6306/com.example.jl.httpsample
       E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
  Process: com.example.jl.httpsample, PID: 6252
  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:372)
  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:105)
  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:264)
  at com.example.jl.httpsample.MainActivity$1GetJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:70)
  at com.example.jl.httpsample.MainActivity$1GetJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:45)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here's my Code

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String json;
    private  String[] data;
    public static final String MY_JSON = "MY_JSON";
    private static final String JSON_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/httpsample.php";
    private  EditText txtuser, txtpass;
    Button btnlogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
        txtuser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        try {
            btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getJSON(JSON_URL);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
    private void getJSON(String url){
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String,Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Please wait...",null,true,true);
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String uri = params[0];

                BufferedReader bufferedReader;
                try{
                    URL url = new URL(uri);
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection =  (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //opens connection duh jl
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

                    while((json = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                       data = json.split(" ");
                    }

                    return data.toString();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return null;
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                txtuser.setText(s);
            }
        }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute(url);
    }
}
```

It was mention that the error came from doInBackground() but im new to Android development so it's hard for me to understand what is happening.

Comment: post the code that includes your implementation of `AsyncTask` as well!

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` throwing the exception its ui elemnt you are running in doinbackground
 method

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with

```
catch (Exception e){          
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return null;
 }
```

Toast needs to run on UI thread which violates the policy as `doInBackgroun` runs in worker thread. Handle the error case in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: could be a comment

Comment: @AbhishekSingh then what else is answer?

Comment: he is getting exception . after this he will raise another question why he is catching exception

Answer (score 0):

Please do use Jsonparser file to run such doInBackground methods. Please find the link below for further knowledge about JsonParser class.

[How to implement Login with HttpURLConnection and PHP server in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345614/how-to-implement-login-with-httpurlconnection-and-php-server-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link :D